# Convert raw http POST to data, write to file in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm running a web server instance in my Flutter app in order to run an image conversion tool, written in JavaScript. The JS code sends a POST command along with a body which contains the raw image data.

Using httpServer and VirtualDirectory, I'm serving all of the required files if JS calls GET, and now when it calls the POST command, I need to convert the POST request to raw data and save it to a file, as it contains the image data I need.

The current web server logic is written in Python. It uses `rfile.read` in order to write the data from the request into a file.

```
contentLength = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
open("output_files/output.%03d.jpg"%frame,"wb").write(self.rfile.read(contentLength))
```

This is what I'm trying to recreate in Flutter. Here's my code so far.

```
_startServer({required String basePath}) async {
    var server = await HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.loopbackIPv4, 8080);
    virDir = VirtualDirectory('$tempDir/converter/')
      ..allowDirectoryListing = true;

    debugPrint(
        "Server running on IP : ${server.address} On Port : ${server.port}");
    await for (var request in server) {
      switch (request.method) {
        case 'GET':
          String path = request.uri.toString();
          if (!path.contains(basePath)) {
            path = basePath + request.uri.toString();
          }
          debugPrint('request uri: $path');
          final File file = File(path);
          if (await file.exists()) {
            request.response.statusCode = HttpStatus.ok;
            virDir?.serveFile(file, request);
          } else {
            debugPrint('Could not find: $file');
            request.response.statusCode = HttpStatus.notFound;
          }

          break;
        case 'POST':
          debugPrint('Content Length: ${request.headers.contentLength}');
          debugPrint('Content Type: ${request.headers.contentType}');

          final File image =
              File('$basePath/videos/frame.${intFixed(frame, 3)}.jpg');
          if (!image.existsSync()) {
            request.response.statusCode = HttpStatus.ok;
            request.response.write('Finished');
            request.response.headers.contentType = ContentType.text;
            request.response.headers.contentLength = 'Finished'.length;
            await request.response.close();
            return;
          }

          final File newImage =
              File('$basePath/output_files/output.${intFixed(frame, 3)}.jpg');

          ByteData data = ByteData(request.headers.contentLength);
          final buffer = data.buffer;
          await newImage.writeAsBytes(
              buffer.asUint8List(0, request.headers.contentLength));
          frame++;
          debugPrint('$frame');

          request.response.statusCode = HttpStatus.ok;
          request.response.headers.contentType = ContentType.text;
          request.response.headers.contentLength = "Success".length;
          request.response.write("Success");
          await request.response.close();
      }
    }
  }
```

Specifically, this part:

```
ByteData data = ByteData(request.headers.contentLength);
final buffer = data.buffer;
await newImage.writeAsBytes(
    buffer.asUint8List(0, request.headers.contentLength));
```

When I set a breakpoint and check `data`, there's no data per-se. Just a list of zeros.

How do I convert the POST request to raw in order to save it to a file? The content length and the content type is correct (image/jpeg), but getting it to data is really stumping me.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error, the solution is to use `await request.single` which outputs a Uint8List, then write that to file as it's a stream of the HTTPRequest object itself.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/single.html

```
final data = await request.single;
final file = File('$basePath/output_files/output.${intFixed(frame, 3)}.jpg');
file.writeAsBytesSync(data);
```